# Wiring a freestanding whirlpool and air tub

Tags: electrical

Wiring with 12 gauge. I’m using a single feed and need to power a bathtub Jacuzzi pump and a separate air blower motor.
The water pump and the air blower each need to pass through a separate 15a gfci.
How should the gfci’s be wired to have power at each gfci, and trip when either the pump -or- blower shorts out.
The pump and blower MUST each pass through a separate gfci.
Thanks

Comment: You post is not clear, can you be more specific

Comment: Can you post a link to the installation manual for your hot tub/whirlpool tub?  I'm having a hard time believing that it requires separate GFCIs yet permits both motors on the same circuit...